# Index JSON by condition

Tags: json, pandas, dictionary

I would like to index this JSON response and get the value attribute by datetime for only one geo_name ('US') in a dictionary / pandas dataframe.

```
"values_updated_at": "2022-01-06T20:17:02.000+01:00",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": 274.38,
        "datetime": "2022-01-06T01:00:00.000+01:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2022-01-06T00:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2022-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8741,
        "geo_name": "US"
      },
      {
        "value": 274.38,
        "datetime": "2022-01-06T01:00:00.000+01:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2022-01-06T00:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2022-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8742,
        "geo_name": "UK"
      },
      {
        "value": 274.38,
        "datetime": "2022-01-06T01:00:00.000+01:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2022-01-06T00:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2022-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8743,
        "geo_name": "Spain"
      },
...
...
```

So far I have tried this but I don't know how to index and filter the response to only show one geo_name by hour.

```
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    values = json_data['indicator']['values']
    prices = [x['value'] for x in values]
    geos = [x['geo_name'] for x in values]
```

Comment: Have you tried the pandas.read_json function? Please see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to provide a valid dictionary in your example. Fixing yours and reading into dataframe, you filter based on your conditions

```
d = {"values_updated_at": "2022-01-06T20:17:02.000+01:00",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": 274.38,
        "datetime": "2022-01-06T01:00:00.000+01:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2022-01-06T00:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2022-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8741,
        "geo_name": "US"
      },
      {
        "value": 274.38,
        "datetime": "2022-01-06T01:00:00.000+01:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2022-01-06T00:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2022-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8742,
        "geo_name": "UK"
      },
      {
        "value": 274.38,
        "datetime": "2022-01-06T01:00:00.000+01:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2022-01-06T00:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2022-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8743,
        "geo_name": "Spain"
      }]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d['values'])
df[df['geo_name']=='US']


    value                       datetime          datetime_utc                   tz_time  geo_id geo_name
0  274.38  2022-01-06T01:00:00.000+01:00  2022-01-06T00:00:00Z  2022-01-06T00:00:00.000Z    8741       US
```